# Twistd amp protocol : Producer/Consumer pattern?

Tags: python, producer-consumer, twistd, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I would like to use protocal to send data between server/client : list of unicode (string) that **exceed  the limit size of 65,535 bytes**. 
A nice and clean solution to deal with the limit size problem is to Implement [Producer/Consumer pattern](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/producers.html).

Unfortunately,  I read the documentation and example but I can't find how to start. 
For small size of transferred data, my amp implementation works very well . I show here relevant parts of my code.

#### command

```
class DataCommand(Command):
    response = [("data", ListOf(Unicode()))]
    errors = {
        KeyError: "KEY_ERROR",
        ValueError: "VALUE_ERROR",
    }
```

#### server

```
class ProducerLocator(CommandLocator):
    def __init__(self,size,N):
        self.data = [id_generator(size=size) for x in range(N)]
    @DataCommand.responder
    def getData(self):
        return {'data':self.data}  ## don't work if is self.data > 64kB
```

#### client

```
class Consumer:     
    d = connect()
    def getData(protocol):
        return protocol.callRemote(DataCommand)
    d.addCallback(getData)
```

Some code to generate data (used above in the factory constructor)

```
import string
import random
def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```